# Django ORM: customize a ListView, and add more information to its queryset

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have a view to list a certain model (lets call it `class A`), like this:

```
class BaseListView(ListView, MultipleObjectMixin):
    http_method_names = ['get']
    order_field = None

    def get_paginate_by(self, queryset):
        session_manager = SessionManager(self.request.session)
        return session_manager.paginate_by.get()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BaseListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        session_manager = SessionManager(self.request.session)
        session_manager.paginate_by.set_to(context)

        return context
```

This view did just what was needed, till now. Now I have to compare the list of objects it retrieves with another list of objects (`class B`).

The objects of class `A` and `B` both have a primary key with their name.

I want to check if any of the objects from `class A` has the same `name` (primary key) as any of the objects in `class B`. In case there is an instance of `A` in `B` I would like to add a certain parameter or something like `is_in_B=True`.

I need this so that I can represent these instances of `A` in a different way in the template.

How could I do this?

This is what I have come up with by myself for the moment:

```
class AListView(BaseListView):
    model = "A"

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(AListView, self). get_query_set()

        all_objects_A = A.objects.all()
        all_objects_B = B.objects.all()

        # modify queryset to indicate which instances of A are present in B
        # No idea how to do this

        return queryset
```

I'm not really sure this is an appropiate approach.

Also, how am I supposed to modify the `queryset` returned by my class so that I can indicate which instances of `class A` share the same `name` as any of the instances of `class B`?

Comment: Are `A` and `B` related at all?

Comment: `A`'s primary key is the field `name` (example: "John Doe"). `B`'s primary key is also its field `name` (example. ''Jane Doe"). So I want to be able to know if there is any "John Doe" in the list of `B` objects and return that information in the queryset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [annotate your queryset with a conditional expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case) to achieve this:

```
from django.db.models import Case, When, Value

def get_queryset(self):
    # This gives you the queryset of A objects
    queryset = super(AListView, self).get_queryset()
    # List of primary keys of B objects
    all_objects_B = B.objects.all().values_list('pk',flat=True)

    # modify queryset to indicate which instances of A are present in B
    return queryset.annotate(
        is_in_b=Case(When(pk__in=all_objects_B, then=Value(True)),
                       default=Value(False))
        )
    )
```

Your queryset objects will now have an `is_in_b` property.

This will work fine if your list of B objects is small. If it is large then I am not sure it is very efficient, and you may need to develop this further to see whether the check (is A in B) can be done directly in the database (possibly requiring raw SQL).

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much @solarissmoke